# Camel JMS is too slow

Tags: jms, ibm-mq, mq

I am using camel 2.14(core, jms and spring) set up a route for a jms endpoint. The JMS provider is IBM MQ (version 7.0.1.4).

When using transactions with no selectors, it is taking about 300 ms per message to read and log one line (no processing).

When not using transactions, it is taking about 20 ms per message to read and log a line 9 no processing).

I need to use transactions there is no option. But it is too slow.

Most of the time is being taken up by the transaction manager (creating and closing the jms session and connections). I have set the cache level to CACHE_CONSUMER,  didnt make any difference (at least not significant, may be 10 ms).

I am trying to find if IBM MQ provides session/connection pools, how to configure? Any help is appreciated.

TIA.

Comment: Are you creating a session and consumer for every message?  You can use the spring caching connection factory to get over this issue.  IBM doesn't provide a JMS connection pool (as these are managed by the application servers effectively).

Comment: its not me, it is camel who is doing it. I AM using cached connection factory, still a new session and connection is being created for every messages. my consumption is transactional, so it makes sense to create a new session. but if i can configure a session/connection pool it will reduce the time it spends in creating the session and connection. It is hard (so far impossible) to find any relevant docuemntation for camel+IBMMQ combination.

Comment: Not an answer, but a link to some valuable reading on the topic: http://tmielke.blogspot.se/2012/03/camel-jms-with-transactions-lessons.html